# Scala: how does List[Double] differ from a List[Int] that is casted to List[Double]?

Tags: scala

The following code compiles fine but crashes at runtime (tested with scala 2.9.2).

```
object Test {

    def fun(x:Double) : Double = { 1.234 * x }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val l1 = List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
        val lfun1 = l1 map fun
        println(lfun1)

        val l2 = List(1, 2, 3).asInstanceOf[List[Double]]
        val lfun2 = l2 map fun // <--- crashes
        println(lfun2)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
List(1.234, 2.468, 3.702)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble(BoxesRunTime.java:114)
    at Test$$anonfun$2.apply(Covariance.scala:11)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:273)
    at Test$.main(Covariance.scala:11)
    at Test.main(Covariance.scala)
```

See the REPL output below for more details.

I come from Java and want to learn Scala, so can somebody please explain to me the reasoning why it crashes and why the compiler cannot detect this? I suppose this has something to do with "views" (Int versus Double) or with "covariance" (List[Int] as List[Double]), but I do not get the point.

---

Here is the individual output in the Scala REPL:

```
scala> def fun(x:Double) : Double = { 1.234 * x }
fun: (x: Double)Double

scala> val l1 = List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
l1: List[Double] = List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)

scala> val lfun1 = l1 map fun
lfun1: List[Double] = List(1.234, 2.468, 3.702)

scala> println(lfun1)
List(1.234, 2.468, 3.702)

scala> val l2 = List(1, 2, 3).asInstanceOf[List[Double]]
l2: List[Double] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val lfun2 = l2 map fun
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble(Unknown Source)
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:9)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:233)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:233)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:76)
    at .<init>(<console>:9)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:11)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:704)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$$anonfun$14.apply(IMain.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Line$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Line.scala:43)
    at scala.tools.nsc.io.package$$anon$2.run(package.scala:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the crash is

> java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

The types `Int` and `Double` are both going to be their Object type at runtime whenever you ever try to use a method on them. Beyond that, it's just the same has how it is in Java. What you're trying to do is something similar to this:

```
List<Double> l2 = ((List<Double>)new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

since `List(1, 2, 3)` is being inferred as a `List[Int]`, which you then cast to a `List[Double]`. And, since an `Integer` is not a `Double`, it crashes. The actual problem will happen when you try to use it in the `map`. Either when you try to make the call, or when it does the calculation itself in the method, the [Java unboxing rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) will get applied, which do something similar to this:

```
((Double)actuallyAnInteger).doubleValue();
```

Causing the `ClassCastException`.

Instead, what you want to do to create a `List` of `Double`s, with `Int` values in the initializer, is do it like this:

```
List[Double] l2 = List[Double](1, 2, 3)
```

That calls the `apply` method of generic type `Double`, rather than of `Int`, and removes the need for a cast.

As for the reason the compiler doesn't correct your problem here, it's because you do `asInstanceOf`. That's basically saying to the compiler "I know what I'm doing doesn't look right, but go ahead and trust me." By explicitly casting, you're telling the compiler not to complain about using the incorrect type.

In response to your comments, the Scala language spec has very little to say about this kind of cast (presumably because it's not idiomatic). I can make a conjecture about why it's this way though. If you look at the docs for `Any`, you see that [`asInstanceOf` is a method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Any@asInstanceOf%5BT0%5D:T0) of the class, rather than something unique in the language like in Java. That means that it will behave much like any other method will. And it's type signature, `asInstanceOf[TO]:TO`, means that the cast you're doing is perfectly type-safe from the compiler's point of view. Presumably this isn't being flagged by the compiler because it's just being treated like any other method would, rather than adding an additional rule (and more complexity) into the language.

Looking through my copy of *Programming in Scala Second Edition* (which is pretty authoritative since it's written by Martin Odersky), this seems to be supported. From section 15.2:

> The operators isInstanceOf and asInstanceOf are treated as predefined methods of class Any which take a type parameter in square brackets. In fact, x.asInstanceOf[String] is a special case of a method invocation with an explicit type parameter String
>
> As you will have noticed by now, writing type tests and casts is rather verbose in Scala. That's intentional, because it is not encouraged practice.

Comment: Yes Java allows no such cast (not even `List<Integer>` to `List<Object>`) as complained by the compiler. The Scala compiler *never* complains about `asInstanceOf` (not even when casting `List[Int]` to `String`), but *some* invalid casts throw an exception at runtime (e.g. when casting `List[Int]` to `String`), while others continue execution (e.g. casting to `List[String]` or `List[Double]`) without errors. Here, the error is postponed to executing `map` because `Double` is "only" an extending view, not a superclass (in which case all would be fine). These three (!) distinct cases irritate me.

Comment: Reformulated in short: is there another explanation that does *not* rely on Java internals, but only on the Scala language specification itself?

Comment: In response to your edit: I just realized that `val l3 = List(1, 2, 3)` even gives a *compile time error* when trying `l3 map fun`, just as it should! So I see now that at the heart of all this trouble lies `asInstanceOf`, as pointed out by you. So I probably should avoid `asInstanceOf` whenever possible (and only use it on collections if I am *absoluetly* sure that all elements get casted to a *supertype*, not just to another view)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, is that does not exist an implicit conversion from Scala `Int` to `Double`, so the line that crashes is one before your line. Really it doesn't crash but that lines does not make what it is supposed to.

Yous should work like this:

```
object StackSample extends App {

  def fun(x:Double) : Double = { 1.234 * x }

  val l1 = List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
  val lfun1 = l1 map fun
  println(lfun1)

  //val l2 = List(1, 2, 3).asInstanceOf[List[]]// <--- crashes

  val l2: List[Double] = List(1,2,3) map (_.toDouble)

  val lfun2 = l2 map fun
  println(lfun2)
}
```

Comment: There does exist an implicit conversion from `Int` to `Double`; a widening conversion, the same as [in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html). He could have done `fun(1)` or `val myInt:Int = 1; fun(myInt)` without any problems.

Comment: Indeed the cast `List[Subtype]` to `List[Supertype]` allows for applying the function `fun(x:Supertype)` at `map` without problems. But the cast `List[Subview]` to `List[Superview]` does *not* allow the application of `fun(x:Superview)`.

Comment: In short: it appears strange that `fun(myInt)` works fine, but `map (myInt => fun(myInt))` fails.